# How to derive the Derivation from a matrix in opencv

Tags: opencv

is there a option in opencv to derive the first Derivation to x and y in ?

**EDIT** mhnm maybe with cvSobel? But how i must set the kernelSize?

greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [getDerivKernels](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=sobel#void%20getDerivKernels%28OutputArray%20kx,%20OutputArray%20ky,%20int%20dx,%20int%20dy,%20int%20ksize,%20bool%20normalize,%20int%20ktype%29) function in opencv. You need to pass it an empty Mat for getting the output.

The default type for this matrix is CV_32F, so make sure you either give the same type Mat or change the ktype to same as the type of the output matrix you are passing.

Size of the kernel can be changed using the ksize option in the same function.

Comment: thx. On http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/image_filtering.html i found a note: `Most often, the function is called with ( xorder = 1, yorder = 0, apertureSize = 3) or ( xorder = 0, yorder = 1, apertureSize = 3) to calculate the first x- or y- image derivative` so it's easy to use cvSobel to derive the first Derivation